# Jmeter - Can I change a variable halfway through runtime?

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, performance-testing

I am fairly new to `JMeter` so please bear with me.

I need to understand whist running a `JMeter` script I can change the variable with the details of `"DB1" to then look at "DB2"`.

Reason for this is I want to throw load at a `MongoDB` and then switch to another `DB` at a certain time. `(hotdb/colddb)`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just defining 2 [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config_(DEPRECATED)) elements pointing to separate database instances and give them 2 different `MongoDB Source` names.

Then in your script you will be able to manipulate `MongoDB Source` parameter value in the [MongoDB Script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script_(DEPRECATED)) test element or in [JSR223 Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) so your queries will hit either `hotdb` or `colddb`

See [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) article for detailed information

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the value from a file in a beanshell/javascript sampler each iteration and storing in a variable, then editing/saving the file when you want to switch? It's ugly but it would work.